# Fit Rotated Video in Display

Tags: gstreamer

When I rotate a test pattern 90 degrees:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoflip method=clockwise ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

I have two problems:

> 1. The output window is distorted unless I maximize it
> 2. The output video window, when maximized, falls outside of my 1920*1080 monitor, so that I only see the upper half of the testsrc pattern

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to `ximagesink`? If I remember correctly there is some additional application logic required to match window dimensions and buffer dimensions. Usually `xvimagesink` or `glimagesink` yield in better results.